# Ionic2: How to use input field values in javascript?

Tags: ionic2

I am playing around with ionic 2 and have the problem that I cannot use the input fields in the javascript area.

This is my page content which shows only a login area with a button

        
          Home

```
  <ion-content class="home">
  <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
          <ion-input type="text" placeholder="User Name" [(ngmodel)]="username"></ion-input> 
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input type="password" placeholder="password"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

    </ion-list>
    <div class="button-center">
        <button (click)="login()">Login</button>
      </div>
  </ion-content>
```

Now I want to access the username in the javascript area, so that it shows the value of the username input field in the alert box.

```
import {Page} from 'ionic-angular';
@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor() {

  }

  login(){
    alert("username: " + this.username);
  }

}
```

But the variable username is always undefined

Comment: try add `username:string;`, it like java you must be create variable before define

Answer (score 0):

You have to define username and password in the component, just before the constructor. And use [(ngModel)] also for the input password.

Comment: Can you show what you mean in the code, I tried  as described without success. The username variable is still undefined

Answer (score 0):

Like what Yin mentioned:

```
<ion-content class="home">
  <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
          <ion-input type="text" placeholder="User Name" [(ngModel)]="username"></ion-input> 
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input type="password" placeholder="password"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
 </ion-list>

    <div class="button-center">
        <button (click)="login()">Login</button>
      </div>
  </ion-content>
```

Your ngModel was not typed properly. Note the caps M.

```
import {Page} from 'ionic-angular';
@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor() {
     this.username = null;    
  }

  login(){
    alert("username: " + this.username);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this, it should solve your challenge

html file

```
   <ion-card>    
     <div padding>

        <ion-list no-lines>
          <ion-item  >
            <

ion-input  round type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" #email></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" #password></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

    </ion-list>
    </div>

    </ion-card>

    <div padding>
    <button ion-button round block (click)="signIn()">Sign In</button>
    </div>
```

and you ts file

```
import { Component, ViewChild  } from '@angular/core';
....
.....

export class LoginPage { 

@ViewChild("email") email;
@ViewChild("password") password;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public alertCtrl: AlertController,private toast: ToastController, private http: Http) {


 }
signIn(){

  if(this.email.value=="" ){

 let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({

 title:"ATTENTION",
 subTitle:"Email field is empty",
 buttons: ['OK']
 });

 alert.present();
  } else
 if(this.password.value==""){

 let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({

 title:"ATTENTION",
 subTitle:"Password field is empty",
 buttons: ['OK']
 });

 alert.present();

}
 else
 {
// carry on with login process
}
```